# Enforcing uniqueness using lightweight transactions in Cassandra

Tags: transactions, cassandra, unique-constraint

This is more of a data-modeling question, but it is related to lightweight transactions because it appears that trying to use this feature is having an impact on how I model my data.

My specific use-case is that I want to enforce uniqueness on specific fields on `INSERT`. Cassandra's documentation has the following example:

```
INSERT INTO customer_account (customerID, customer_email) 
VALUES (‘LauraS’, ‘lauras@gmail.com’)
IF NOT EXISTS;
```

In my particular case, I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS plugins (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id uuid,
    name text,
    slug text,
    major_version int,
    minor_version int,
    patch_version int
);
```

The constraint I want to enforce is that the combination of `user_id`, `slug`, `major_version`, `minor_version`, and `patch_version` needs to be unique. I cannot simply do:

```
INSERT INTO 
    plugins (
        user_id, 
        slug, 
        major_version, 
        minor_version, 
        patch_version
    ) VALUES (...) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

This is because I need `name`, and `id`. However, including `name`, and `id` will still cause things to be written in because `IF NOT EXISTS` will fail due to the fact that the `id` will be different (at the very least), and `name` may be different as well.

Does this mean that I need to maintain a separate table that only has `user_id`, `slug`, `major_version`, `minor_version`, and `patch_version`? I would then attempt to write to this table, and look at the result of the operation. If the write succeeds, I will go ahead and populate all the other associated tables.

I know that denormalization is a fact of life with Cassandra; I just want to make sure that it makes sense here to create this table just to handle the case of uniqueness. If this approach doesn't make sense, please do suggest another one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT ... IF NOT EXISTS` creates a new row if no row with provided key exists. It does not compare column by column, only the key. If you want to enforce the uniqueness of `user_id`, `slug`, `major_version`, `minor_version` and `patch_version` then those columns need to form a primary key.

Comment: I see. So does this mean I would need a separate table that maintains those fields as a primary key? My original table has `id` has the primary key, because I frequently do lookups by the id.

Comment: Cool! That's what I was looking for. I just wanted to know if it made sense to make another table just to enforce this constraint.

Comment: If you think about it, all indexes and unique constraints in traditional relational databases do have almost the same structure as tables, behave almost like tables. They're just being used internally